# Transforming matrices in a differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is from Dupont et al., "Simplified density-matrix model applied to three-well terahertz quantum cascade lasers", PRB 81, 205311 (2010):

*Equation (3) (...) can be rewritten as a 16x16 system of linear equations*

Equation (3) [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mP4E.jpg)
:
[image: eq 3]

16x16 system [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTzm0.png):
[image: system]

How do I perform such transformation?

Comment: It's good to add a picture of the system if you could't write it in Latex. An the Equation as well

Comment: But I did, aren't they visible?

Comment: No! it is not :-(

Comment: I moved the images to another hosting service and added links in case they are not visible.